# TensorFlow: No module named Pandas (I already have Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, module, pip, path

```py
WORKSPACE_PATH = 'Tensorflow/workspace'
SCRIPTS_PATH = 'Tensorflow/scripts'
APIMODEL_PATH = 'Tensorflow/models'
ANNOTATION_PATH = WORKSPACE_PATH+'/annotations'
IMAGE_PATH = WORKSPACE_PATH+'/images'
MODEL_PATH = WORKSPACE_PATH+'/models'
PRETRAINED_MODEL_PATH = WORKSPACE_PATH+'/pre-trained-models'
CONFIG_PATH = MODEL_PATH+'/my_ssd_mobnet/pipeline.config'
CHECKPOINT_PATH = MODEL_PATH+'/my_ssd_mobnet/'

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x {IMAGE_PATH + '/train'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/train.record'}
!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x{IMAGE_PATH + '/test'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/test.record'}
```

running which I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 21, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 21, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

I already have installed Pandas and Tensorflow before through pip.

Thank you for helping me out!

OS: MacOS Catalina 10.13.5

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment, or a conda environment? Have you checked that the Python executable you're using when you run `python` is the Python in which you installed  `pandas`? (I.e. what's the output of `which python` on *nix or `where python` on Windows?) Etc. Beyond that there's not much help you can get without more context. The code you added also probably doesn't have anything to do with the import error, so I would cut it down to make it brief.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any virtual environment to run your code? If not I would suggest you create a Virtual Enviourment first then install all the dependencies and then run the code.

Install Conda or Virtualenv or any other and then try.

Comment: I have tried using virtualenv but it doesn't even connect to the server, it says: "a connection to the notebook server could not be established. the notebook will continue trying to reconnect. check your network connection or notebook server configuration." I have even downgraded tornado to 5.1.1 as mentioned by someone.

Comment: I see. Can you try to install conda. And create a virtual environment there and install the dependencies and then run the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing pandas using conda cause conda somehow installs the package globally (base python env)